# Does Spring 3.0 really support JSR-286?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, portal, jsr286

Does Spring 3.0 Portlet MVC really support JSR-286 aka Porlet 2.0? I've seen anecdotal  mentions of it but nothing in any documented form.

If so, has anyone successfully implemented a JSR-286 plugin with Spring 3.0. If yes, on what platform?  Any good reference information, or better yet, a sharable implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/16/spring-framework-3-0-goes-ga/:

> - **Rich native Portlet 2.0 support**: Spring MVC fully supports Portlet 2.0 environments and Portlet 2.0’s new event and resource request model. Includes specialized mapping facilities for typical portlet request characteristics: `@ActionMapping`, `@RenderMapping`, `@ResourceMapping`, `@EventMapping`.